# In an amplifier, does the gain knob boost or attenuate the input signal?

Tags: amplifier, gain

I'm thinking specifically about guitar amplifiers, but I'm guessing this applies to all audio amplifiers.

I understand the practical function of a gain knob, but what's not clear to me is whether the gain knob is simply a potentiometer that attenuates the incoming signal, meaning if the gain knob is all the way up, it's simply letting the signal through unaffected, or if the gain knob controls some sort of boost circuit that actively increases the input signal strength before sending it to the preamp.

Or does the knob somehow directly affect the operation of the preamp making it provide more amplification or something like that?

Comment: It's bolted to a potentiometer, which is a resistive divider. Resistive dividers don't have gain. There may be an amplifier before the gain knob but that's another matter.

Comment: Is it literally just a potentiometer wired between the input and the preamp, (like the volume knob on a guitar) or is it controlling something more complicated?

Comment: That depends most likey on the amplifier. I have never seen a guitar amplifier with simply a pot on input though, it has always been a knob that affects the gain or attenuation after the input stage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be either when determined by marketing. Two common configurations are shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdc094.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1a: Fixed gain pre-amp with preceding attenuator. 1b: Variable gain pre-amp.*

- 1a is simple but has the disadvantage that the noise from OA1 is constant even with the input turned to zero.
- 1b has the advantage that as the gain is reduced so is the noise.

(Gain in the example circuits is -R2/R1 or -R5/R4.)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen circuit (b) in an audio device -- it's always (a), sometimes with a preceding fixed-gain buffer.

Comment: @Tim, the guys over at [Elliot Sound Products](https://sound-au.com/project24.htm) have something similar based on a John Linsley Hood / Doug Self / Baxandall design. Another [hobby design](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/small-amplifier-circuit/) here. (See section 5.)

Comment: I tried to make one. It is really hard to make it stable over 10dB or more of a gain range.

Comment: Another common configuration is to have a pot wired as an attenuator feed a non-inverting amplifier configuration or a voltage follower followed by a fixed-gain inverting amp.  In configuration #1 as shown, use of large values for R1 and R2 will increase the circuit's sensitivity to noise, while using small values will make the circuit more sensitive to wiper noise in R3.   It may also be good in configuration #2 to add a resistor in series with R5 to set a limit on maximum gain.  The circuit as shown could, with an ideal amp, yield any gain from R5/R4 to infinity, but...

Comment: ...with any practical amplifier there will be a limit to practical gain, and the circuit will have a more useful adjustment range on the pot if a series resistor limits gain to that value.

Comment: @supercat, wouldn't Figure 1b's gain go from \$ -\frac 0 {R4} \$ to \$ -\frac {R5}{R4} \$. No infinity - even if the wiper loses contact with the track.

Comment: Right, though 1b _is_ still more problematic if the wiper loses contact: it will jump to the maximum-gain setting then, whereas in 1a it will jump to -∞. This is particularly problematic with a logarithmic pot (as you probably want for a gain) in the lower end of the range, because it'll then jump from quiet to DEAFENINGLY BLASTING OUT OF THE SPEAKERS.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: You're right.  It's the non-inverting config where gain goes to infinity.

Answer (score 5):

Mostly, it's a potentiometer that selects a proportion of the signal to feed through the subsequent amplification stages [like from this datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000128.pdf). Red marks by me: -

[image]

And this one [from this datasheet](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/839826.pdf) with my red marks: -

[image]

But it can be "digital" where the action of the knob turning clicks a switch a number of times (might be subtle to tell if you didn't know) will ramp the volume up or down: -

[image]

The above from [this datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TDA8551_T.pdf?) with my red marking.

Comment: Could you please provide links or citations for the sources of these images?

Comment: They are from device data sheets (or slightly red-ink amended).

Comment: OK, but can you give credit to the original creators of these images?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the chip manufacturer's are the creators of the images and surely you don't expect me to find the names of the guys who worked on the diagrams? Think about what you are saying.

Comment: No, but I think you should give links to the web sites where you got the images or citations to the documents that you copied them from. Maybe this will be helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @ElliotAlderson they are directly from data sheets and I have red marked them as appropriate. Cut n paste into paint then mark up. That’s my usual method but, do I really need to explain such a basic exercise. Should I state that the diagrams are made by such and such a means each and every answer I make that I embed a picture? Do I actually need to do that?

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to follow the policies of this site. You need to "Provide a link to the original page or answer" and "Provide the name of the original author". It doesn't matter **how** you copied them or marked them...the important thing is that you make it clear **where you got the original content**. It's just common courtesy...until it becomes copyright infringement.

Comment: Let's see - the first one is from the data sheet for the TDA2030, the 2nd from the datasheet for the LM386 and the third from the datasheet for the TDA8551. They all seem to be from manufacturers that have been bought out.

Comment: @DDuck I hope you are not saying that degrades my answer.

Comment: @Andy - just pointing out the obvious.  I could easily find the source pdfs from the images (no need for a link, just searching on the part number) and that you'd chosen older parts with better artwork. These datasheets are all in the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @DDuck yeah but I was “asked” to cite my sources. Sure, to those who know it should be obvious lol.

Answer (score 2):

Typically (for audio) it's an attenuator placed in between portions of the circuit such that the signal level is high enough that there will not be much disagreeable background hum or hiss with the pot cranked all the way down. That also means that pot wiper noise does not tend to cause too much disagreeable scratchiness when the pot is adjusted.

You would not, for example, want to attenuate the signal going *into* a preamp.

In instrumentation it might directly affect the gain, for various reasons related to how much adjustment range is required, how accurate the gain has to be and so on.